# loop through an array and extract desired data (python)

Tags: python, arrays

So I have and array named data. There is contents inside that looks like this

```
data[0] = ['46.09', '24.76', '0.70', '0.53', '27.92', '0.00',]
```

I want to be able to loop through this section and extract only the numbers and toss the commas and apostrophes so my desired output would look like:

```
number[0] = 46.09
number[1] = 24.76
number[2] = 0.70
and so on........
```

any help will be greatly appreciated

Thank You!

Comment: I tried the conversion to a flot but i get this error..."Value Error could not convert string to float"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like all you are trying to do is loop over a list, and convert the strings to floats:

```
for elem in data[0]:
    val = float(elem)
    print val
```

Or you could just map them to floats:

```
number = map(float, data[0])
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
number = [float(s) for s in data[0]]
```

Comment: I tried this and it tells me: "Value Error: cannot convert string to float"

Comment: @user2353003: That means you have non-numeric strings in your list. Did you manage to work that out?